# How to set Audio streaming URL as AVAudioFile?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation

I am following this tutorial :https://miguelsaldana.me/2017/03/13/how-to-create-a-soundcloud-like-waveform-in-swift-3/

My code given below .There is an exception :

> Error Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=2003334207 “(null)”
>   UserInfo={failed call=ExtAudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)fileURL,
>   &_extAudioFile)}

```
   let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: AudioLink)  //Got Exception Here

    let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: file.fileFormat.channelCount, interleaved: false)
    print(file.fileFormat.channelCount)
    let buf = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format!, frameCapacity: UInt32(file.length))
    try! file.read(into: buf!)



    //     print("floatArray \(readFile.arrayFloatValues)\n")
    //self.waveFormView.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Comment: what is "AudioLink" are you using NSTemporary Directory. Pls also add your audio link/

Comment: @MAhipalSingh  Thanks for asking .                                                                                                 Take this link as Example -                                                                               let url : URL = URL(string: "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3 ") 
SetAudioVisulizer(AudioLink: url)